Hirsch length of the center of a polycyclic group
I am working with polycyclic groups. A group $G$ is called polycyclic if there exists a subnormal series
$$ 1 = G_0 \vartriangleleft G_1 \vartriangleleft ... \vartriangleleft G_{k-1} \vartriangleleft G_k = G$$
such that each quotient $G_i/G_{i-1}$ is cyclic.
The Hirsch length of a polycyclic group $G$ is the amount of infinite cyclic factors of a polycyclic series of $G$ and is a group invariant.
I have the following properties for the Hirsch length (see Polycyclic groups by Segal):

If $H$ is a subgroup of $G$, then

$h(H) \leq h(G)$
$h(H) = h(G) \iff [G:H]<\infty$
if $H$ is normal in $G$, $h(G) = h(G/H) + h(H)$


Now my question is the following:
Is there any relation between the Hirsch length of the center of $G$, $h(Z(G))$ and $h(G)$ itself?
Of course, if the center is a finite index subgroup of the group itself, the Hirsch lengths are equal. I do not know however, how to proceed in the general case.
Remark: I only work with torsion-free nilpotent groups, so maybe with this extra condition, a clearer relation can be achieved.
Thanks in advance!

What is $h(G)$?

$h(G)$ is the Hirsch length. There are a few restrictions, but not many. I don't think you can have $h(G) = h(Z(G))+1$, for example, but almost anything else is possible.

Sorry, I edited the "shouting" and hope you don't mind. Why do you "need" a relation between $h(G)$ and $h(Z(G))$?

I believe that for any integers $m,n$ with $1 \le m \le n-2$, there exists a torsion-free nilpotent group $G$ with $h(Z(G))=m$, and $h(G)=n$. I don't have the energy to write down a proof, but here are a couple of examples.
$m=2$, $n=4$: $G=\langle a,b,c,d \mid [a,b]=c,[a,c]=[a,d]=[b,c]=[b,d]=[c,d]=1 \rangle$.
$m=1$, $n=5$: $G=\langle a,b,c,d,e | [a,b]=c,[a,c]=d,[a,d]=e,[a,e]=1, b,c,d,e \ {\rm all\ commute}\ \rangle$.
In general. we can take a direct product of a free abelian group of rank $m-1$ with a nilpotent group of class $n-m$ with cyclic centre.

Maybe I'm missing something, but is it obvious $m=n-1$ doesn't work?

@SteveD I think you would end up with a finite index subgroup $H$ with $H/Z(H)$ infinite cyclic, which is impossible.
